# Create dynamic row as per the list recievied in CSS/XSLT

Tags: css

I want to create the row as per the list i am receiving using xslt and css. Currently my xslt looks like below. In the below code i am reading the DataList using xsl:for-each and I want to create a new row if my data list size is more then 7. Could anyone please help on this.

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="97px" style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;color:#9EB7B4;">DATA:</td>

        <td>
            <table style = "width:100%; ">
                <tr style="height:35px">
                    <xsl:for-each select="DataList">
                        <td><a href="#{generate-id(DataName)}" ><xsl:value-of select="DataName"/></a></td>

            </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Any body can help on this ?

Comment: To solve the above issue, i am thinking to add a counter and will increment it for each column. once it reaches to 7 will create one more row. So can anyone will let me know how t increment the counter and check in the above code